# Store value when pressing a link in while loop. php

Tags: php, sql-server, session, while-loop

So i got a little problem i just cant figure out to solve..

So i got a While loop that is printing from my database:

```
$resultArray = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Kunde WHERE fornavn LIKE '%".$searchq."%' ";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);

if ($stmt === false){
    die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), tue) );
}

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><th>Kundenr</th><th>Fornavn</th><th>Etternavn</th><th>Tlf</th><th>Epost</th><th>Produktnr</th><th>Adresse</th></tr>";


while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH)) 
{
    $resultArray[] = $row;

    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<a href="ajax.php">'.$row[0].'</a>';
    echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[3] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[4] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[5] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[6] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
```

I now want to send the variable i press to a new php file. To do this i am using:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['kundenr'] = $resultArray[0]['kundenr'];
```

The problem is that i my $resultArray i must write a number inside [], which define what loop number it are saving ['kundenr'] from. So now i have [0], it is always sending ['kundenr'] from the first loop. This works fine as long I dont have 10 search result to choose from.

So are here anyone that now a easy fix? somthing to store the loop value from my click or something?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what do you want to achieve here. Could you please try to explain it again. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, okay, the code in the question is somefile.php, and here iam searching for all "Kunde" (Costumers in English), with the name i Type in the searching field.  

It will then Display all the customers in my database with that name. I now want to click on a costumer and a new page should come up with all Product and Cases that countains the Same "Kundenr" (CostumersID in English).

Comment: I made this work fine with AJAX, but then I just get the information I want on the same page. Instead i want a whole new page.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now. I think that querying database on your new page would be a better idea, you could do something like: `<a href="ajax.php?kunder='.$row['kundenr'].'">'.$row['kunder'].'</a>'` and then in ajax.php it would query the database again to get all information about that customer rather than using Session as a cache unless you have some performance issues.

Comment: Also, I would recommend escaping data from the database (with `htmlspecialchars()` or `htmlentities()`) before using them for building HTML.

Comment: hmm.. okay, but how will I now acsess the "CostumerID" in the ajax.php file? I used Session to do this.. any idea?

Comment: Never mind, figured it out! Thank You! did it your way :)